# GiHub Pages only showing README file

Tags: github-pages

I'm trying to deploy my GitHub repo using GitHub pages to my domain but only see the README file rendering. [this](https://github.com/andykeem-dacreator/Portfolio) is a link to the repo, and I'm deploying it on andykim.info. I set the source as the main branch /root, I do not have a gh-pages branch.

I tried reconfiguring the webpack.config.js file because in my package.json file I have

```json
"scripts": {
  "build": "webpack",
  "predeploy": "npm run build",
  "deploy": "gh-pages -d build"
}
```

Comment: And what exactly do you think is there to be deployed?! Read https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/